# Nginx TCP stream routing based on source IP

Tags: nginx, tcp

I have configured nginx as a reverse proxy for a TCP (non-http) stream.
I'd like to apply different routing for a particular source IP address - can this be done, and how? I'm aware of recomendations for the http module using the *if* directive, but that doesn't seem to work for these streams.

Existing configuration:

```
stream {
  server {
    listen 8000;
    proxy_pass staging;
  }
}

upstream staging {
    server 1.2.3.4:8000;
}
```

Desired configuration (not working):

```
stream {
  server {
    listen 8000;
    proxy_pass staging1;
    if ( $remote_addr ~* 4.5.6.7 ) {
        proxy_pass staging2;
    }
  }
}

upstream staging1 {
    server 1.2.3.4:8000;
}
upstream staging2 {
    server 1.2.3.44:8000;
}
```

This gives error '24314#24314: "if" directive is not allowed here', since it doesn't apply for the stream module - is there any other functionality how I could achieve this result?

Answer (score 3):

in case some people are still wondering you can achieve this using a map:

```
stream {
  upstream staging1 {
    server 1.2.3.4:8000;
  }

  upstream staging2 {
    server 1.2.3.44:8000;
  }

  map $remote_addr $backend_svr {
    4.5.6.7 "staging2";
    default "staging1";
  }
  server {
    listen 8000;
    proxy_pass $backend_svr;
  }
}
```

[ref](https://serverfault.com/questions/886997/nginx-tcp-load-balancing-if-directive-is-not-allowed-here-in-stream-context)